# Batch script to automatically delete empty folders - need help adding exceptions

Tags: windows, batch-file

My batch experience is rather limited but I did manage to write the following script to delete all empty subfolders of my target folder.

```
set "Target=C:\Target" 
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir "%Target%" /A:D /B /S ^| sort /r') do rd "%%i" 2>NUL >NUL
```

My problems are: 
1. I would like to be able to keep the first layer of subfolders intact and only delete empty folders in the following layers. 
2. If it is possible I would also like to skip certain folders completely based on their name.

Is it possible to do that or would i need to write the script for all of the subfolders i want to clean up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below was tested on following folder structure in folder **C:\Target**

- **Folder1**

  - **Folder To Delete**
  - **Folder To Keep A**
  - **FolderToKeepB**
- **Folder 2**

  - **Folder To Keep A**
  - **Not Empty Folder**

    - File in Folder.txt

The resulting folder structure after running the batch file below was

- **Folder1**

  - **Folder To Keep A**
  - **FolderToKeepB**
- **Folder 2**

  - **Folder To Keep A**
  - **Not Empty Folder**

    - File in Folder.txt

Just the single folder **Folder To Delete** was deleted as this one should not be always kept and it was indeed empty.

```
@echo off
rem For each subfolder in C:\Target do ...
for /D %%D in ("C:\Target\*") do (
    rem For each subfolder in found subfolder of C:\Target do ...
    for /D %%S in ("%%~D\*") do call :DeleteFolder "%%~S"
)
rem This goto :EOF results in exiting the batch file.
goto :EOF

rem Subroutine for easier comparing the name of the current
rem subfolder with the name of the subfolders to always keep.
rem The goto :EOF commands below just exit the subroutine.
:DeleteFolder
if "%~nx1"=="Folder To Keep A" goto :EOF
if "%~nx1"=="FolderToKeepB" goto :EOF

rem Delete this subfolder which fails if it is not empty.
rem The error message is suppressed by redirecting output stream
rem stderr (standard error) with handle 2 to the NUL device.
rd "%~1" 2>nul
goto :EOF
```

For more details on the used commands read help output printed into a console window on running

- For command [call](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490873.aspx): `call /?` or `help call`
- For command [for](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx): `for /?` or `help for`
- For command [goto](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490914.aspx): `goto /?` or `help goto`
- For command [rmdir (rd)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490990.aspx): `rd /?` or `help rd` or `rmdir /?` or `help rmdir`
- [Using command redirection operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx)

Comment: Doesn't handle empty directories three or more levels deep.