# Copying files from folders in root directory containing same names related to batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, abaqus

I want to know something about batch files. I am completely new to batch files writing.

I am using Hyerstudy 12.0 Software for Running Abaqus jobs. I want to run three Abaqus jobs simultaneously.

I have some files that have the same names but contain different data. I cannot change the name of these files for all 3 jobs as Hyperstudy creates 4 folders from the root directory for running jobs.

I am using in my batch file:

```
copy ..\..\..\..\Abaqus_job.inp Abaqus_Job.inp
```

I have created 3 folders in root directory for all 3 jobs that contain the files with same names. I want to copy these folders and I want to access the data from the files that these  folders contain.

How can I do that with a batch file?

Comment: Would you please edit your question and show use the folder structures and the files in the folders to copy as otherwise it is impossible for us to help you. You can use [lists](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) as in my answer on [Batch script to automatically delete empty folders - need help adding exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27346099/3074564) or use code blocks with appropriate indented lines to show us the folder structures. We would need both - before and after -  folder structures.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. I hope I can explain correctly. I have a root Directory contaning Path "E:\..." . I have 3 Folders in it  say Folder1,Folder2,Folder3 which contains same 3 files say (A,B,C) but all 3 files have different data. I cannot copy them in one directory as they will be deleted..Also I cannot change there Names.Example:JOB-1-Folder1 ie job-1 needs to access the files from Folder-1 in root Directory.Similarly Job-2-Folder2 ie job-2 needs to access files from folder2 Job-3-Folder3.